# StringBuilder in For Loop

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have this JSON

```
{
    "elements": [{
            "company": "Microsoft",
            "isValid": "yes"
        }, {
            "company": "Google",
            "isValid": "no"
        }, {
            "company": "Apple",
            "isValid": "yes"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to build a string output that is like this

```
Microsoft is OK

Google is NOT OK

Apple is OK
```

If isValid = yes, then it is 'IS NOT OK'. Else it is 'OK'

Here my code

```
for (i in result) {
 var output = new StringBuilder();
 if (result[i].isValid == "yes") {
    output.append(result[i].company);
    output.append(" is OK\n");
  } else {
        output.append(result[i].company);
    output.append(" is NOT OK\n");
  }
}
console.log(output.toString());
```

But output is only the last one (Apple is OK);

PLease help

Answer (score 4):

Put the `StringBuilder` otside of the for loop.
Your code produces new `StringBuilder` every time you enter the loop.

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
for (i in result) {
  if (result[i].isValid == "yes") {
    output.append(result[i].company);
    output.append(" is OK\n");
  } else {
    output.append(result[i].company);
    output.append(" is NOT OK\n");
  }
}
console.log(output.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `console.log(output.toString());` is out of the for loop, so this will be executed for the latest `output`("Apple is OK" in this case). Taking `console.log(output.toString());` inside for loop (as in below snippet) will give the output for all the values of `elements`.

```
for (i in result) {
 var output = new StringBuilder();
 if (result[i].isValid == "yes") {
    output.append(result[i].company);
    output.append(" is OK\n");
  } else {
        output.append(result[i].company);
    output.append(" is NOT OK\n");
  }
console.log(output.toString());
}
```

Comment: Not very efficient, since you have to create new StringBuilder every time you enter the loop.

Comment: Yes! Your answer is more optimal.